# Decomposition of a von Neumann Algebra into Factors

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I know that a von Neumann algebra on a separable Hilbert space can be (uniquely) decomposed into factors. But is there any non-trivial example showing how we can explicitly compute it?

Non-trivial: I mean it is not a factor itself, not abelian or of finite dimension.

Comment: You should also consider the finite-dimensional case as trivial, otherwise the following gives an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-dimensional_von_Neumann_algebra

Comment: I'm puzzled as to what you might mean by "explicitly computing" a factor decomposition.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux thanks for your comment. I have updated my question.

Comment: @NikWeaver Similar to the theorem given in the finite-dimensional case, to identify the type of each factor.

Comment: @Fan: the word *type* has a specific meaning in the [factor theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Factors): there are type ${\rm I}_n$, ${\rm I}_{\infty}$, ${\rm II}_1$, ${\rm II}_{\infty}$, ${\rm III}_{0}$, ${\rm III}_{\lambda}$, ${\rm III}_{\infty}$. The type does not characterize completely the factor, except in the [amenable case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Amenable_von_Neumann_algebras) (${\rm III}_{0}$ excepted).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes I am aware of that. I have read a bit about the characterization of each type. Given a von Neumann algebra $W$, which is non-trivial. Let's say I want to see whether it is possible to define a trace on $W$, so the idea is to decompose it into factors and define a trace for each factor (if possible) and add them up. How shall I do the first step then? Is there any reference which I can look up to? Thanks for your reading!

Comment: @Fan: if your goal is to define a trace (if it exists) then it is true that the decomposition works (a trace exists iff there is no type ${\rm III}$ component); but note that according to the definition of your von Neumann algebra, it is sometimes possible to define a trace directly. The main reference on von Neumann algebras is Takesaki book (three volumes). I'm not really an expert on von Neumann algebras, so I can't give you a more specific reference. I advice you to complete your post with the explanation of your goal, and then to advertise that to Nik Weaver.